# In Bottom Navigation Bar , icon is not getting highlighted even after i selected that icon .How to change it?

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

By default in every activity only home icon is getting highlighted.

1. How to change the highlight the icon which  is selected ?
2. How to change the default highlighting icon ?
3. Where to make the changes in which `activity_main.xml` or `MainActivity.java` or else menu xml file ?

Login icon is pressed but home is getting highlighted :
[selector.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNhE9.png)

[MainActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpeIR.png)

[activity_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1byzA.png)

[nav_items.xml-menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM103.png)
[I pressed the second icon,activity is changed but still home is getting highlighted in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEiGO.png)

Comment: You need to share your code as text

Comment: have you refer this articale  https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/

Comment: Yes, i have added the images of my code in the question,you can check it and say if there are any errors

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Add a `selector.xml` in drawable folder like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/beyaz" android:state_enabled="true" />
<item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

In activity_main.xml  add `app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"`

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"

    />
```

Comment: I am unable to get even though i made the changes

Comment: I have added the code images in the question,can you check it and say me if  there are any changes to be  made

Comment: sorry I am not able to find the issue, just try with  some other color instead of white